# Duplicate Record Sets object is not available for Salesforce Platform Profile

Tags: administration, system-admin

1. In production org, for Salesforce Platform License Profile, Duplicate Record Sets tab is not listed.
2. In Dev Org, for Salesforce License Profile, Duplicate Record Sets tab is set to 'Default On', but for this profile user, still Duplicate Record Sets tab is not visible on All Tabs.

Comment: I have already checked https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_management_duplicate_record_sets.htm&type=5 ... but this didn't helped

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate Management is only available for Sales Cloud, Service Cloud, or Sales & Service Cloud licenses. So users with other licences won't see the objects and components of Duplicate Management.